# String boundingRect calculated height doesn't match UITextView content height

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, uitextview

I have a UITableView with variably sized cells. The height is based on a block of text that I need to display so I need to measure the text.

I'm just using some Lorem Ipsum text:

> "Nullam est elit, rutrum volutpat scelerisque eu, tincidunt ut magna.
>   Quisque sit amet odio quis eros lobortis cursus. Phasellus mauris
>   augue, mattis a posuere sit amet, dictum sit amet ipsum. Praesent
>   velit sapien, tristique ut pellentesque eget, venenatis in est.
>   Curabitur accumsan lacus nec ultricies finibus. In commodo, turpis at
>   auctor lobortis, augue ipsum tincidunt lorem, vitae fringilla libero
>   magna eget tortor. Sed et ultrices odio, et viverra diam. Mauris
>   semper non lorem varius sollicitudin. Maecenas nec dui lectus. In hac
>   habitasse platea dictumst. Quisque sapien ex, pretium id vehicula
>   eget, tempus at nisl. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent
>   per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Aliquam vel sollicitudin
>   velit, efficitur accumsan sem. Quisque id urna blandit, cursus justo
>   sed, aliquet velit. Nullam id ipsum pellentesque, gravida nulla ut,
>   tempor libero."

When I call `ceil(text.height())` it returns `386.0` tall, but when I put that text into the UITextView and print out the content size of the UITextView it says the content is `422.0` tall. (i.e. my text is getting cut off because the UITextView isn't tall enough to display everything.)

Why is there a difference?

I'm using the following String extension to calculate the height of the text:

```
extension String {

    func height(withConstrainedWidth width: CGFloat, font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {
        let constraintRect = CGSize(width: width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)
        let boundingBox = self.boundingRect(with: constraintRect, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: font], context: nil)

        return boundingBox.height
    }

}
```

Then in `tableView(heightForRowAt:)` I calculate the height of the text and add it to the space above and below the textview to get the full cell height (this was more elegant before I started debugging this):

```
let textviewWidth = self.view.frame.size.width-CGFloat(32)
let spaceAboveTextView = CGFloat(45)
let spaceBelowTextView = CGFloat(16)
let textHeight = ceil(text.height(withConstrainedWidth: textviewWidth, font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17.0)))
let height = spaceAboveTextView + textHeight + spaceBelowTextView
```

I've verified that the UITextView is using the System Font of size 17, which matches with my code above.

I've verified the frame of the UITextView (after being displayed) is `(16.0, 45.0, 382.0, 385.6667)` so the `spaceAboveTextView=45` is accurate and the `width=382` is accurate. I've also checked the constraints on the UITextView and it has a bottom constraint of 8pt to the margin and the margin is 8pt for a total of 16pt in the `spaceBelowTextView` as well.

So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: For clarification: Are you using UITextView to support multiline text.  If so, refactoring to use a UILabel.  Just set the number of rows to 0 and setting up your constraints.  Absent other needs, setting the UITextView to not scroll should make it self size like any other view.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Using this code did help me calculate correct height: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32613836/1226304

Answer (score 4):

Most likely you have a problem because you forgot to factor in the `textContainerInset` (maybe also other insets of your text view).

By default, they are 8 from top, left and right.

Try to change your code to this:

```
let textviewWidth = self.view.frame.size.width-CGFloat(32)-textView.textContainerInset.left-textView.textContainerInset.right
let spaceAboveTextView = CGFloat(45)+textView.textContainerInset.top
// bottom space is 0 by default. But lets add it just in case ;)
let spaceBelowTextView = CGFloat(16)+textView.textContainerInset.bottom
let textHeight = ceil(text.height(withConstrainedWidth: textviewWidth, font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17.0)))
let height = spaceAboveTextView + textHeight + spaceBelowTextView
```

I just tested this solution and it works for me with system font of size 17. Please let me know if this doesn't work!

Comment: I had previously looked at contentInsets, but they were all zero, and I looked at the textContainer but didn't see the textContainerInsets. Those accounted for 16 more pts, so that definitely helped, but I'm still missing something somewhere.

Comment: This solution helps with short strings, but on a longer strings difference in heights is huge (more than 250 points on ~1700 words attributed string)

Answer (score 1):

Measuring text for display on the screen is difficult because the system changes fonts and spacing and such to make the text more legible on the CRT (for example it can substitute screen fonts for vector fonts).  Even then it's possible to have some overlaps when using characters with high ascent or descent like Å.

NSString and NSAttributedStrings have measurement routines that calculate the bounding size of text in the current graphics context.  See [boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsstring/1530195-drawwithrect?language=objc).  In the past what I've done to force raster metrics when I didn't have a convenient CGContext was create a small offscreen bitmap context (say 1 pixel in size) and set that to the current context while measuring the text.

Another thing you want to look for is the fact that UITextView draws into it's `textContainer` and not into it's frame.  IIRC the default container is the frame inset by 4 or 5 pixels.